# Please verify the pertinency of the mappings and retry

Tags: business-objects-sdk

Using the BusinessObjects BI 4.1 RESTful SDK, the following error appears when I try to change the universe:

```
<error>
   <error_code>101</error_code>
   <message>The change source operation has failed. Please verify the pertinency of the mappings and retry.</message>
</error>
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Do all the mapped objects have a status of "ok"?

Comment: yeah Joe , but what i found was it was working good for reports without context .I m nt sure is this a problem ?

Comment: Do you have a similar error message when you change the data source manually from WebI?

Comment: nope , its wrking fine if we try manually..

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the sample code provided in the SCN post [Changing Dataproviders for a Webi Report using RESTful Web Services](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-45986), referenced in SAP Note [1988540](https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1988540).

After you've verified the steps and are still running into the same issue, consider testing with a different WebI document and/or a different universe to see if that has any effect.

Comment: Its changing but some objects are getting deleted .. can you help me with that?